# How to configure spring framework WebClient with reactor.netty ProxyProvider for proxy authentication?

Tags: java, spring, proxy

I try to connect my application with a generic rest service. In my case to access in internet you shuold connect with a proxy. I wrote a simple Rest Java Client using WebClient of `Spring Framework`. To add the proxy I first create the HTTP client and within the configuration set the proxy parameters, then set the connector to the Web Client.

I'm using `jdk1.8.0_181` and spring boot 2.1.2. But to do the tests I wrote a main.

To connect with the proxy I tried in the following ways:

1. As a first attempt I added a defaultHeader to the creation of the WebClient:

```java
builder.defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.PROXY_AUTHORIZATION, "Basic "+Base64.encodeBase64("my_user:my_password".getBytes()) )
```

2. As a second attempt I tried to use a ProxyAuthenticator:

```java
Authenticator.setDefault(new ProxyAuthenticator("my_user", "my_password"));
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "my_host");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "my_port");
```

having defined the `ProxyAuthenticator` separately:

```java
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

class ProxyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

    private String user, password;

    public ProxyAuthenticator(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password.toCharArray());
    }
}
```

without success.

Here is my clean code without all the tests done previously:

```java
public static WebClient getClient(String url, String httpHeaders, String mediaType, boolean isProxy) {
        Function <String, String> pwd = username -> "my_password" ;

        Builder builder = WebClient.builder();

        if(isProxy) {

            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                    .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient ->
                            tcpClient.proxy(proxy -> proxy.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP)
                                    .host(my_host)
                                    .port(my_port)
                                    .username(my_username)
                                    .password(pwd)
                                    .nonProxyHosts(my_exclusion)
                                    ).option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 1000));
            ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
            builder.clientConnector(connector);
        }

        return builder.defaultHeader(httpHeaders,mediaType).baseUrl(url).build();

    }

    public static Mono<?> getCall( WebClient client3, String uri, Class<?> bodyType) {

        UriSpec<RequestBodySpec> request = client3.method(HttpMethod.GET);

        RequestBodySpec requestBodyspec = request.uri(uri);

        ResponseSpec response = requestBodyspec.retrieve();

        return response.bodyToMono(bodyType);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebClient client3 = getClient("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com", HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, true);

        Mono<?>  result = getCall(client3, "/todos/1", JsonNode.class);

        System.out.println(result.block().toString());

    }
```

The error that is raised by my code is the following:

> Exception in thread "main" reactor.core.Exceptions $ ReactiveException: io.netty.handler.proxy.ProxyConnectException: http, basic, proxy.host.it => jsonplaceholder.typicode.com:443 , status: 407 Proxy authentication required

While the output I was expecting is printing the result.